# Como calcular diferença de datas que estão uma linha anterior com MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, data

Eu tenho uma tabela onde eu registro o momento em que determinada solicitação teve o seu `status_id` alterado. Essa tabela eu chamo de `historico_status_solicitacoes`.

Nessa tabela, eu tenho os seguintes campos: `id`, `status_id`, `solicitacao_id`, `usuario_id`, `created_at`.

Para cada solicitação que tem o status alterado, um registro é inserido.

Assim:

```
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | status_id | solicitacao_id | usuario_id | created_at          |
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-29 17:28:46 |
|  2 |         2 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-29 17:38:50 |
|  3 |         3 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-29 17:48:16 |
|  4 |         4 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-29 18:58:46 |
|  5 |         5 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-29 19:31:46 |
|  6 |         6 |              1 |          1 | 2018-10-30 10:20:00 |
+----+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
```

O que eu preciso fazer? Eu preciso fazer uma consulta, onde eu consiga computar a diferença em minutos entre uma linha e outra, considerando a data menor para a data maior (que no caso pode ser o `id` também, já que é criado sequencialmente, e o valor maior sempre é o mais recente).

Eu fiz alguma coisa parecida para calcular o saldo atual, usando a linha anterior, mas não faço a minima ideia de como trabalhar com diferença de datas no MYSQL.

Alguém pode dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Caramba, não tem 10 segundos que postei a pergunta e já tem um negativo? O que está acontecendo? Poderiam explicar o motivo?

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei, mas por que fazer isso no banco? Não pode passar direto para o front?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam se forem muitos retornos, eu poderia querer recorrer a uma paginação. E, numa paginação, você não teria o valor anterior caso estivesse na segunda página. Eu até pensei em fazer a pergunta no sentido de levá-la pro lado do Laravel, mas nesse caso, prefiro no banco de dados mesmo.

Comment: mas tem que pensar na questao de performance também, isso pode pesar mto pro banco, algo que seria simples no front-end.
ps.: tb nao fui eu quem negativei xD

Comment: @aa_sp sinceramente, dependendo do tamanho da paginação, compensaria mais fazer o cálculo no banco, não? Por que um status poderia se repetir no histórico. Claro que é um caso raro, mas suponhamos que ocorra um caso de eu ter 1000 registros. É bom pensar por esse lado, porque o objetivo do site é ter uma resposta mais canônica, que possa ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters precisa avaliar, dependendo as vezes uma variavel simples de comparação resolveria. Mas voce, que conhece o sistema, precisa avaliar e testar as opções, pensando não só como a base está agora, mas no futuro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não seria interessante criar uma coluna `diferenca` e na hora de inserir calcular e informar a diferença para o ultimo registro?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos isso aí vai contra a normalização de banco de dados, não? Calcular os dados tem mais chances de ter o valor certo do que uma coluna que pode ser alterada erroneamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na consulta abaixo ele relaciona com o menor ID que é maior que o atual

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.created_at, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,A.created_at,B.created_at) AS timedifference 
FROM historico_status_solicitacoes A 
LEFT JOIN historico_status_solicitacoes B ON B.id = (
        SELECT MIN(B2.ID) FROM historico_status_solicitacoes B2 WHERE B2.ID>A.ID
    )

ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer um `SUB-SELECT` pegando todos os registros com datas menores que a atual, ordenar pela data em ordem decrescente e limitar em 1, se realmente todos os registros tiverem a data sequencial, você sempre pegará o anterior:

```
select a.id, a.status_id, a.solicitacao_id, a.usuario_id, a.created_at, IFNULL((
    select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(a1.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-00'), DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-00'))
    from historico_status_solicitacoes a1
    where a1.id <> a.id AND a1.created_at <= a.created_at
    ORDER BY a1.created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
), 0) diff
from historico_status_solicitacoes a;
```

Estou utilizando a função `DATE_FORMAT` para ignorar os segundos e sempre calcular o minuto cheio.

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7834464/2).

Comment: +1 boa, cara :D

Answer (score 1):

Wallace a consulta pode ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT A.id, A.created_at, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,A.created_at,B.created_at) AS timedifference 
FROM historico_status_solicitacoes A INNER JOIN historico_status_solicitacoes B ON B.id = (A.id + 1) 
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Só uma observação, nesse caso o resultado será em **'SEGUNDOS'**, para deixar em uma granularidade maior ( Minutos ou horas), basta trocar o seguinte trecho na sintaxe SQL:

> ...TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,...

Comment: Boa ideia. O problema é que as vezes o `id` nem sempre pode ser `+1` o subsequente.

Comment: entendi.. é que me baseei nessa parte: (que no caso pode ser o id também, já que é criado sequencialmente).

Comment: Eu acho que me expressei mal. Na verdade, o `id` mais recente sempre terá o valor maior que o anterior.